# CentOS 7 can't install php module

Tags: centos, php, installation

I have installed php 7.2 on centos 7. I tried to install the module redis but it seems id doesn't want to download. Here is the error of the command `yum install php-pecl-redis` :

[image]

I tried installing it with `yum install php72w-pecl-redis` but it seems like it doesn't found the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed PHP from the `remi-php72` repository, but then you disabled that repository. Enable it and try installing `php-pecl-redis` again.

Comment: Here is the content of the file /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php72.repo
 https://pastebin.com/nN6tsZn4

Comment: Now post the output from trying to install the package again. And please don't use screenshots. Copy and paste text.

Comment: Also notice than you probably need php-pecl-redis4 for latest version

Answer (score 1):

I would

```
yum install php-pecl-redis --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=remi-php*
```

granted that you still have  /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php72.repo

when cherrypicking packages from different repos you always have to do work on top.